# Is there any way to be informed when Microsoft update an essential package?

Tags: frameworks, botframework, bots

Every so often there will be a package updated that the bot framework service requires to be up to date.  This time, it was something to do with the identity model.  My bot is just sitting and running, and then we found out that it hasn't even been reporting errors  (why we didn't look sooner) because nothing could authorise a request to it.

I think it's a bit ridiculous that a simple out of date package could bring down the entire bot, and I'm not sure if there's any documentation or newsletters telling us that certain things will be updated.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're saying that your bot stopped working due to a package update?  How did you determine this?  (You can watch http://blog.botframework.com for notices.)

Comment: Yeah, or rather an out of date package.  Updating them to the latest version fixed the problem.

Comment: I am not aware of the requirement to update any packages to ensure a bot continues to function properly.  What version of the Bot Builder sdk was the bot using previously, when it quit working?